# Wordpress display related articles on page

Tags: wordpress

I currently have a custom page in Wordpress (with the PHP Execution plugin). On this page I'm displaying dynamic content, and I would like to be able to show, at the bottom of this page, a dynamic list of related Wordpress articles. I'm currently using Similar Posts, but since my page doesn't have any tags (I assume this is why it doesn't work), it doesn't show any related articles. Is there any easy solution for this?

**Edit:**
I was thinking about another way to solve my problem - to display a short list of the articles that share the same tag. For example, on my website www.domain.com/tag/same-tag would display a list of articles that contain a tag "same-tag". Is there any way to display 5 or so of these articles (I would only be using article titles and author) ?

Comment: You could maybe modify the tag script to search for keywords in the post title's instead of tags. Could you post the script?

Comment: It's a plugin, so it's pretty long - but here is the website: http://rmarsh.com/plugins/post-options/.

Comment: Okay, I did some further googling and found this: http://www.yarpp.org/. Might be what you're looking for?

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work for what I'm trying to do. I edited my post to include another solution I'm looking for. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to show pages with the same tag.
First of all, you should get current post tags using [wp_get_post_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags)
When you have it, select pages with the same tags using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters). Don't forget to exclude current page. In order to select random related pages set orderby to rand at WP_Query.